# Trying to filter with keywords and also specific column with dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table that can be searched with using keywords, but also want to include a drop down box that will also be part of the filtering.  Below is my code.  I can select a state from the drop down, which will filter the states, but as soon as I type in a keyword it reverts back to all of the states.  I would like to filter by state first by using the drop sown, then use the keywords for that state only.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
<title>States</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

<div id="Header">

</div>
<div id="MainBody">

<h2>Search</h2>
<input type="text" id="myInputJob" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="" title="Type Here">

  <select id="StateDropdown" oninput="filterTable()">
  <option>All</option>
  <option>CA</option>
  <option>WA</option>
</select>

<div id="TableJob">
<table id="myTableJob">
<tr class="header">
<th>City</th>
<th>State</th>
<th>Keyword1</th>
<th>Keyword2</th></tr>
<tr><td>San Francisco</td><td>CA</td><td>Blue</td><td>Red</td></tr>
<tr><td>San Diego</td><td>CA</td><td>Blue</td><td>Red</td></tr>
<tr><td>Seattle</td><td>WA</td><td>Blue</td><td>Red</td></tr>
<tr><td>Salt Lake City</td><td>UT</td><td>Blue</td><td>Red</td></tr>
<tr><td>Las Vegas</td><td>NV</td><td>Blue</td><td>Red</td></tr>
</table>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
<script>

function myFunction(event) {
var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
input = document.getElementById("myInputJob");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
table = document.getElementById("myTableJob");
 tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

 for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
table.style.display = ""
if (document.getElementById('myInputJob').value == '') { 
table.style.display = "";

} else {
table.style.display = "";

}
    td_1 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
    td_2 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
    td_3 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    
    if (td_1 || td_2) {
   if (td_1.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) == 0 || td_2.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) == 0 && td_3.innerHTML == document.getElementById("StateDropdown").innerHTML) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
  } 
}

function filterTable() {

  let dropdown, table, rows, cells, state, filter;
  dropdown = document.getElementById("StateDropdown");
  table = document.getElementById("myTableJob");
  rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  filter = dropdown.value;

  
  for (let row of rows) { 
    cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td");
    state = cells[1] || null; 
    if (filter === "All" || !state || (filter === state.textContent)) {
      row.style.display = ""; 
    }
    else {
      row.style.display = "none"; 
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

I feel like I need to put an AND condition in there, something like this

if (td_1.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) == 0 || td_2.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) == 0 **&& td_3.innerHTML == document.getElementById("StateDropdown").innerHTML) {**  but that doesn't work.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way is:

declare `var tr` and `table` outside of those two functions so you can use those variables in in both functions.

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTableJob");
var tr=table.querySelectorAll('tr');
```

When you search the state it will filter `trs` and set the unwonted to `display none`, so after state search save in `tr` only those who are visible at end of the `function filterTable()`

```
tr = table.querySelectorAll('tr:not([style="display: none;"])');
```

Now your function `myFunction(event)` will use only already filtered (if filtered) `trs`.

BTW your Keyword2 search is not working at all, but that was not the question.

```js
var table = document.getElementById("myTableJob");
var tr = table.querySelectorAll('tr'); 

function myFunction(event) {
var input, filter, td, i;
input = document.getElementById("myInputJob");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();



 for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
table.style.display = ""
if (document.getElementById('myInputJob').value == '') { 
table.style.display = "";

} else {
table.style.display = "";

}
    td_1 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
    td_2 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
    td_3 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    
    if (td_1 || td_2) {
   if (td_1.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) == 0 || td_2.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) == 0 && td_3.innerHTML == document.getElementById("StateDropdown").innerHTML) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
  } 
}

function filterTable() {

  let dropdown, rows, cells, state, filter;
  dropdown = document.getElementById("StateDropdown");
  rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  filter = dropdown.value;

  
  for (let row of rows) { 
    cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td");
    state = cells[1] || null; 
    if (filter === "All" || !state || (filter === state.textContent)) {
      row.style.display = ""; 
    }
    else {
      row.style.display = "none"; 
    }
  }
tr = table.querySelectorAll('tr:not([style="display: none;"])');  
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="Header">

  </div>
  <div id="MainBody">

    <h2>Search</h2>
    <input type="text" id="myInputJob" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="" title="Type Here">

    <select id="StateDropdown" oninput="filterTable()">
      <option>All</option>
      <option>CA</option>
      <option>WA</option>
    </select>

    <div id="TableJob">
      <table id="myTableJob">
        <tr class="header">
          <th>City</th>
          <th>State</th>
          <th>Keyword1</th>
          <th>Keyword2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>CA</td>
          <td>Gray</td>
          <td>Red</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>San Diego</td>
          <td>CA</td>
          <td>Blue</td>
          <td>Red</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Seattle</td>
          <td>WA</td>
          <td>Blue</td>
          <td>Red</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Salt Lake City</td>
          <td>UT</td>
          <td>Blue</td>
          <td>Red</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Las Vegas</td>
          <td>NV</td>
          <td>Blue</td>
          <td>Pink</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @ikiK this is good stuff. I took out the && line and that fixed the Keyword2 column.  It worked for me when my table was inside the HTML.  When I tried to add the windows.onload function to call a js file that has the table in there, this is the error I am now getting.  TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null at line 55 - which is this line of code var tr = table.querySelectorAll('tr');  I called the JS file, then declared my variables.  I am not sure what the difference is having the table in the HTML or calling a JS file that has the table in there.

Comment: @RickD im on mobile now, but that just means selector didnt cacth the table, on top of my head its just matter of timing, DOM was loaded probably before table, try to declare those two varables at end of your js where you generate table.

Comment: also its window.onload, not windows, is you table even loaded?

Comment: Thanks for the help on this.  Yes correct, I meant to say window.onload.  I am trying to move the 2 variables inside the JS file after the table.function. Not sure how to show you my JS file, but i have my table then <script>var table = document.getElementById("myTableJob"); var tr = table.querySelectorAll('tr'); </script>  I am getting a GetManuals is not defined. What is the correct way to add variables inside a JS file? I use ' and / at the beginning/end of my rows.  soemthing like <tr><td>San Francisco</td><td>CA</td><td>Gray</td><td>Red</td></tr> \ OR </table> '

Comment: @RickD Sorry, cant help you like this. I answered the question about search and it is working as it should in snippet. You have problem with your setup and JS Scope. You should ask another question where you will explain how your setup is ruining.

Comment: @RickD BTW if the file you are including table is really JS like you say, with extension `.js` you should just put variable declaration literary at very end of the file, not HTML table itself, without `<script>` tags.... Like I said its hard to suggest anything else without seeing your setup.